# What does "over a round" mean?

Tags: meaning

What does "over a round" mean in this sentence:

> Let's put this matter to rest over a round, shall we? My treat.

(It's from Pillars of Eternity).

Comment: The *round* means a round of drinks.

Comment: (And "My treat" means the speaker is offering to pay for said drinks.)

Comment: Probably drinks.  But maybe a round of golf.  Or other activities that have "rounds".

Comment: Context would help. Is this the video game, or something else? What time period and place is it set in?

Comment: Pillars of Eternity is a book set in the early Middle Ages England. So not golf.

Comment: I disagree that this is for ELL. "a round" is idiomatic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Over a round" means while drinking a round of drinks.

"My treat" means the speaker is buying the drinks.